# Edit string array, keep only first letter from value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return an array with only first letters of values of original string array.

For example: Let's say I have following array:

```
var array = ["gsss", "osgs", "ortr", "dges"];
```

and I need some function that will return this:

```
["g", "o", "o", "d"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map()` to loop thru the array. Get first letter of the string by `o[0]`

```js
var array = ["gsss", "osgs", "ortr", "dges"];
var result = array.map(o => o[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly i need

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` and `charAt` to do it

```js
var array = ["gsss", "osgs", "ortr", "dges"];
var result = new Array();
array.forEach(v =>{
  result.push(v.charAt(0));
});
   console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `map()`

```
array.map(item=> {return item.charAt(0)});
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be:

```js
// on the grounds that you may want to repeat the
// functionality but for a different index, we use
// compose a named function that takes two arguments.
// haystack: Array of strings from which you wish to
// retrieve the characters;
// index: (optional, defaults to 0), specifies the
// index from which you wish to retrieve the characters:
let charsAtNFrom = (haystack, index = 0) => {

    //  here we iterate over the Array using
    // Array.prototype.map(), with an Arrow function:
    return haystack.map(
      // 'str' represents the current String of the Array
      // of Strings over which we're iterating; and we return
      // the character at the specified index:
      (str) => str.charAt(index)
    );
  },
  stringArray = ["gsss", "osgs", "ortr", "dges"],
  firstLetters = charsAtNFrom(stringArray);

console.log(firstLetters);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed - so you should change  ...firstLetters = charsAtNFrom(stringArray, 1);... to be ...firstLetters = charsAtNFrom(stringArray, 0);...

Comment: @gavgrif: it's embarrassing, sometimes, just how far my mind wanders midway through writing answers. Thanks! (And, of course, edited)

Answer (score 0):

Return a new array with Array Reduce:

```
let arr = ["gsss", "osgs", "ortr", "dges"];
let newArray = arr.reduce((newArr, curVal)=>{
    return newArr.push(curVal.charAt(0));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = new String[]{"gsss", "osgs", "ortr", "dges"};

        char array1[] = new char[array.length]; //creating another Character Array

        for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++) { //taking first character for each element of the Array
        array1[i]= array[i].charAt(0);  
        }
```